# build a path tree for URIs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a list of URIs for which I need to create a tree/object structure. For example here is the URIs

```
/api/abc/xyz/abc/cde
/api/xyz/abc/d3/d2
/api/abc/cde/d3/d2
/api/abc/cde/d1/d2
```

The result tree should look like this

```
{
    api: {
        abc: {
            xyz: {
                abc: {
                    cde: {}
                }
            },
            cde: {
                d3: {
                    d2: {}
                },
                d1: {
                    d2: {}
                }
            }
        },
        xyz: {
            abc: {
                d3: {
                    d2: {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to do this with javascript. Is there any algorithm that I can use to build this? I started with the below code but I'm kinda lost!!

```
paths=['/api/abc/xyz/abc/cde', 
'/api/xyz/abc/d3/d2', 
'/api/abc/cde/d3/d2',
'/api/abc/cde/d1/d2' ];

 var apiResources = {};
    for(var i in paths) {
        var path = paths[i];
        //split by '/'
        var parts = path.split("/");
        var node = apiResources;
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            if (!node[parts[i]]) {
                node[parts[i]] = {};
            }
            node = node[parts[i]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems straightforward. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 Yes I did. I posed my code in the edit now. Thank you

Comment: But that already does what you want? You might want to skip the first element though (`["", "api", "abc", "xyz", "abc", "cde"]`).

Comment: Thank you I got it working I think!! https://jsfiddle.net/theswcjc/

Answer (score 0):

```
var string="a/b/c";
keys=string.split("/");
var obj={};
var index=obj;
for(let i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
index=index[keys[i]]={};
}
```

Obj should now contain the string as an object. You can repeat that with multiple atrings